# Tweepy + Twitter API v2 does not return additional fields

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy, twitterapi-python, twitter-api-v2

I am trying to search for tweets or do user lookup with Tweepy and Twitter API v2. The issue is that I do not get requested additional fields, e.g.

```
user = client.get_user(id=17874544, user_fields=['created_at','description','entities','location','pinned_tweet_id','profile_image_url','protected','public_metrics','url','verified','withheld'])
```

The returned user object only contains the default user fields

```
Response(data=<User id=17874544 name=Twitter Support username=TwitterSupport>, includes={}, errors=[], meta={})
```

However, I get all these with a direct request to API with `curl`.
What could be the problem and how can it be solved?